# POST request from php

Tags: php, post, curl

I need a php page, when loaded, to send a POST request automatically without using a submit button or any user input.  I don't need to do anything with the response.

I simply need to POST "8" to www.mydomain.com

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 8);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => 8));
```

On your domain edit script to:

```
echo $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: Still not working.  I now have:      $url = 'http://mydomain.com/'
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => 8));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

Comment: I try `$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/'; $ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => 8));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);` and works fine for me

Comment: Thanks.  I'd vote this up but my rep isn't good enough... just like in high school.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a strange request .. you should consider using a key for the value of 8.

You can, however, get the POST body on `http://www.mydomain.com/` by reading `'php://input'`.

```
//on www.mydomain.com/index.php
echo file_get_contents('php://input'); //8
```

By the way you also have `$curl` instead of `$ch` on the third setopt.

Comment: `file_get_contents` sends a `GET` request

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste I assume you mean `file_get_contents('http://www.mydomain.com/')` would send a GET request.  That is *not* what I'm suggesting at all.  Please read my answer carefully; if you care to try it, please test it out for yourself